# Swift: declaration 'description' cannot override more than one superclass declaration

Tags: clang, swift

I have a structure of inheritance similar to the one below. I'm adopting the Printable protocol and diligently override description property. I have encountered a bizarre error that seems to be unknown to Google at this point in time, that is prompted for the Third class, and references Second and First class.

To add insult to injury, the code below actually compiles fine, but my full code does not. Commenting the properties out on Second and Third solves the problem and the code compiles, tests pass etc.

Swift inheritance chapter provides pointers to this.

Does anyone know what it means and which circumstances trigger it?

> /Users/ivanhoe/Dropbox/swift/convergence/Processable.swift:124:18:
>   error: declaration 'description' cannot override more than one
>   superclass declaration
>       override var description : String {
>                    ^ /Users/ivanhoe/Dropbox/swift/convergence/Processable.swift:85:18:
>   note: overridden declaration is here
>       override var description : String {
>                    ^ /Users/ivanhoe/Dropbox/swift/convergence/Processable.swift:28:18:
>   note: overridden declaration is here
>       override var description : String {

```
import Foundation

class First : NSObject, Printable {

    override var description : String {
        return "first"
    }
}

class Second : First {

    override var description : String {
        return "second"
    }

}

class Third : Second {

    override var description : String {
        return "third"
    }

}

println(Third())
```

Comment: "the code below actually compiles fine" Then you should get it to the state when it no longer compiles. I know, this sounds strange, because usually you go the other way, but if you would like to show the error, you need broken code.

Comment: I agree, but I am obviously not able to do it. This was the reason I started with a clean slate on the mockup above. I have asked a specific question about an error message that looks pretty defined, yet completely unknown / unobserved in the wild.

Comment: Is it important to you that it is a subclass of NSObject? Why?

Comment: makes no real difference in my code currently, and could be safely skipped, and also makes no difference for the bug, but I tried to give as accurate a representation of the bug circumstances

Comment: correction: NSObject is there to make assertions like XCTAssertEqual work, since I'm developing something using TDD... of course I could just use XCTAssert etc. but this isn't really the point of the question

Comment: I've found that there is a known bug in Swift (different error though) manifesting itself in similar circumstances, maybe someone finds this useful: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/229668?tstart=0

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same thing, and also for the `description` property of `Printable`, however it seems to apply to any property! Can Swift really only override a property once??

Comment: What is `Printable`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same problem for me, solved by doing:

```
func customDescription() -> String {
    return ""
}

override var description: String {
    return customDescription()
}
```

so you can override function as many times as you want to

Comment: It works well (I don't understand why yet, not far into Swift), and it seems you can even skip the `customDescription` function declaration and just return the result you want directly from the `override var description`.

Answer (score 2):

What is the Printable Protocol? ;-)

You could use a Getter of a property as

```
var description: String {
    get {
        return "This is a test";
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. This overrides the getter in the NSObjectProtocol. That way it uses the description string when printing to the console.

Comment: use CustomStringConvertible protocol instead nowadays

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my Mac now, but I would try removing the `override` in `First`. `override` is needed when subclassing but not when implementing a `protocol`.

Comment: It doesn't help. You get the error when you attempt to override an already-overridden property. It seems the compiler can only handle one override.

Comment: @devios1 Are you sure about that? http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59c00f686663ac5ff2561211

Comment: @Alexander Not sure anymore. That was three years ago. It does seem to be fixed now.

Comment: @devios1 Oh lol, didn't realize this question was so old. Somebody must have commented on it and dumped it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with [SKTiled](https://github.com/TomLinthwaite/SKTilemap) when overriding [SKTiledScene](https://github.com/mfessenden/SKTiled/blob/master/Sources/SKTiledScene.swift). In my situation I wanted to override a mouse event for OS X.

The error was as follows:

```
Declaration 'mouseUp(with:)' cannot override more than one superclass declaration
```

The problem here is that the mouse events are declared in a class extension:

```
#if os(macOS)
extension SKTiledScene {

    override open func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {}

    override open func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        guard let cameraNode = cameraNode else { return }
        cameraNode.mouseMoved(with: event)
    }
    override open func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {}
    override open func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {}
    override open func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {}

    override open func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        guard let cameraNode = cameraNode else { return }
        cameraNode.scrollWheel(with: event)
    }
}
#endif
```

I could solve my issue to override the method in my own SKTiledScene subclass by re-implementing the extension:

```
extension SKTiledScene {
    open override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        try! SceneManager.shared.transitionToScene(MainMenuScene.self, withAnimation: .fade)
    }
}
```

I do wonder if I can be sure my extension is always loaded instead of the one from the SKTiled framework, but it seems to work well for now.